Washed out UV texture
I have this simple UV texture and I have tried multiple ways for this, from trying changing the actual texture background and fixing it in the shader node, but nothing seems to work out.

[File Deleted]

You have a shader that looks like this:

It takes the texture and mixes it with white using the image itself as a factor. So the brighter the parts on the image the more of the image is visible on white. So the shader is doing what it's supposed to and there are no problems there, but maybe you wanted to mix the image on top of some color using its alpha as factor:


I have tried on giving the texture it self a green background, and try different mixing, and it still looked washed out, any suggestion?
The black color doesn't seem to register or something, since the font are almost black all over
I have never have this problem before even with other product I made

Yes. I suggest using my suggestion from the answer I have just written. What's wrong with mixing the image using its alpha as factor?  What result do you want?

What do you mean using it's alpha factor? sorry I'm quite new to this

It's in the sceenshot attached. You should go to the Shader Editor, and adjust the inputs of the Color Mix node so that the Alpha output of the Image node goes in to the Factor input of the Color Mix node. I can explain in more detail if you want, but I would really suggest learning these basics from some beginner tutorials - it's just easier that way. Is it more clear, or do you need further clarification? I could make a GIF...

ohh. I know about that but I don't know the name, I have put the factor to the texture image so I'll try something else, heck I might just try make a big texture image and apply it there.
Thank you

@LaLa, it works. Have a look at the screenshot. No need to experiment, just try the exact suggestion - plug the Alpha to the Factor. You can change the color to anything you want as well. If that's not what you want, then you can adjust the contrast in the image, or try something else.

wait, so sorry, I didn't see that using the alpha factor is the one that you mean, I get it now, thank you so much

Try changing alpha mode from Straight to Premultiplied on the image node as well, it seems that's the format for the alpha mask in the image.

yes, thank you I'll try that

@LaLa You should really try to do some tutorials on materials and texturing to understand the basic methods of mixing colors, textures etc. No offense, but it might really help trying to understand answers given here.
